# Sessions with SPA application and API

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

We are using ASP CORE 2.x (API) with a SPA (ReactJS), I need to know what is the best strategy to track users sessions. The issue is mainly for unauthenticated users, let say we have a shopping cart. The cart is stored in the database, how do you keep the cart items of a guest user? When a guess leaves the site and comes back, we need to show the cart items.

I was planning to have a session generate by the server and saving it to the client side (in a cookie), but this means that I need to call a “ensure” session on from the client site to the server…  and keeping track of the session in the db.

Any alternative or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can persist the shopping cart items to `localStorage`, and then when the user comes back just rehydrate it.
I would recommend `redux-persist` if you use `redux`.

Answer (score 1):

I would associate the cart of the guest to a generated guid stored with the cart (ID?}. Passing this through cookies, the next time the guest comes, if the cookie exists and refers to a cart, I reload it.
You can set some timestamp to clean pending cart on a regular base from your DB.